# React nuts and bolts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm learning React/Redux and am trying to modify a tutorial project to act more like an application I once worked on in Angular. I have a list of objects in a functional component using array.map to generate table rows. I want to edit each row in place by toggling between display and edit mode for a given row of data. I can put the logic in to display the correct elements/components for each mode, but haven't gotten the markup to act properly. I have an icon with an onClick event handler that toggles modes.

```
 let oldCourse = { isEditing: false };
    
function onEditClick(course) {
    debugger;
    course.isEditing = true;
    oldCourse = course;
}
```

The cell that holds the icon is an example of the type of thing I'm trying to do. I realize that I could do this same thing using a ternary expression inside a single icon element, but this was a simple first cut.

```
<td>
    {course.isEditing && (
        <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faTrashRestore}
            size='md'
            cursor='pointer'
            onClick={() => onCancelClick(course)}
        />
    )}
    {!course.isEditing && (
        <span onClick={() => onEditClick(course)}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} size='md' cursor='pointer' />
        </span>
    )}
</td>
```

Since data binding is unidirectional with React/Redux unlike Angular I haven't figured out the mechanics yet. What I want to happen is for the cell contents to toggle as described, but would like suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Here is the entire source of the component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "../../fontawesome";
import { faTrashAlt, faTrashRestore, faEdit, faEye, faSave } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

export function CourseList({ courses, onDeleteClick }) {
    const [course, setCourse] = useState({ isEditing: false });
    const [oldCourse, setOldCourse] = useState(course);

    function onEditClick(course) {
        debugger;
        const updatedCourse = { ...course, isEditing: true };
        setCourse(updatedCourse);
        setOldCourse(updatedCourse);
    }

    function onCancelClick() {
        setCourse({ ...oldCourse, isEditing: false });
    }

    return (
        <table className='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th />
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {courses.map(course => (
                    <tr key={course.id}>
                        <td>
                            <a href={"http://pluralsight.com/courses/" + course.slug}>
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye} size='md' cursor='pointer' />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <Link to={"/course/" + course.slug}>{course.title}</Link>
                        </td>
                        <td>{course.authorName}</td>
                        <td>{course.category}</td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        {course.isEditing && (
                                            <span onClick={() => onCancelClick()}>
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon
                                                    icon={faTrashRestore}
                                                    size='md'
                                                    cursor='pointer'
                                                />
                                            </span>
                                        )}
                                        {!course.isEditing && (
                                            <span onClick={() => onEditClick(course)}>
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} size='md' cursor='pointer' />
                                            </span>
                                        )}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {!course.isEditing && (
                                            <span onClick={() => onDeleteClick(course)}>
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon
                                                    icon={faTrashAlt}
                                                    size='md'
                                                    cursor='pointer'
                                                />
                                            </span>
                                        )}
                                        {course.isEditing && (
                                            <span>
                                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSave} size='md' cursor='pointer' />
                                            </span>
                                        )}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}

CourseList.propTypes = {
    courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onDeleteClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        courses: state.courses,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CourseList);
```

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `useState` to remember certain parts of the state needed in your application. Checkout the example below:

```
const [course, setCourse] = useState({ isEditing: false })
const [oldCourse, setOldCourse] = useState(course);
    
function onEditClick(course) {
    const updatedCourse = {...course, isEditing: true};
    setCourse(updatedCourse)
    setOldCourse(updatedCourse);
}

<td>
    {course.isEditing && (
        <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faTrashRestore}
            size='md'
            cursor='pointer'
            onClick={() => onCancelClick(course)}
        />
    )}
    {!course.isEditing && (
        <span onClick={() => onEditClick(course)}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} size='md' cursor='pointer' />
        </span>
    )}
</td>
```

In the context of multiple courses:

```
export function CourseList({ courses, onDeleteClick }) {
  const [editingStatusByCourseId, setEditingStatus] = useState({});
  const [courseToUpdate, setCourseToUpdate] = useState({});

  function onEditClick(course) {
    setEditingStatus({ ...editingStatusByCourseId, [course.id]: true });
    setCourseToUpdate(course);
  }

  function onCancelClick(course) {
    setEditingStatus({ ...editingStatusByCourseId, [course.id]: false });
    setCourseToUpdate({});
  }

  function onSaveClick(course){
    // call your redux action to save/update the course.
  }

  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th />
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Author</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th />
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {courses.map((course) => {
          const isInEditMode = editingStatusByCourseId[course.id] === true;

          return (
            <tr key={course.id}>
              <td>
                <a href={"http://pluralsight.com/courses/" + course.slug}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={"faEye"} size="md" cursor="pointer" />
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <Link to={"/course/" + course.slug}>{course.title}</Link>
              </td>
              <td>{course.authorName}</td>
              <td>{course.category}</td>
              <td>
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      {isInEditMode && (
                        <span onClick={() => onCancelClick(course)}>
                          <FontAwesomeIcon
                            icon={"faTrashRestore"}
                            size="md"
                            cursor="pointer"
                          />
                        </span>
                      )}
                      {!isInEditMode && (
                        <span onClick={() => onEditClick(course)}>
                          <FontAwesomeIcon
                            icon={"faEdit"}
                            size="md"
                            cursor="pointer"
                          />
                        </span>
                      )}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      {!isInEditMode && (
                        <span onClick={() => onDeleteClick(course)}>
                          <FontAwesomeIcon
                            icon={"faTrashAlt"}
                            size="md"
                            cursor="pointer"
                          />
                        </span>
                      )}
                      {isInEditMode && (
                        <span onClick={() => onSaveClick(course)}>
                          <FontAwesomeIcon
                            icon={"faSave"}
                            size="md"
                            cursor="pointer"
                          />
                        </span>
                      )}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: I thought of doing something like that but have been unable to connect to Redux properly. I created mapStateToProps and connect functions (function mapStateToProps(state, id) {
    const course = state.courses.length > 0 ? state.courses.find(course => course.id == id) : {};
    return {
        course,
        courses: state.courses,
    };
}

export connect(mapStateToProps)(CourseList);
) but can't get things to work properly and Babbel fails to compile, complaining about the export statements. What would be the proper syntax for them.

Comment: could you add your redux logic and the error to your post?

Comment: Hm, it says the edit queue is full, so I can't add the code to the post with nice formatting. However, I've fixed the transpile error and this is the code after and external to the component function. 
CourseList.propTypes = {
    courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onDeleteClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        courses: state.courses,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CourseList);

Comment: and is there an typescript error or does the view not get updated?

Comment: The view doesn't get updated. When I debug, the course pertinent to the row where click the edit icon doesn't change after using setCourse. So I'm still missing some way to connect things properly.

Comment: You mean that when you click on the faEdit icon it doesn't change to the faTrashRestore? Did you check if the onEditClick is invoked?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. onEditClick is invoked and the updatedCourse is set properly. The isEditing property of the course object is not set to true even though setCourse is called.

Comment: I've added the source for the component. I was trying to edit the wrong theing before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231703/discussion-between-flyfisher1952-and-maartendev).